# PHP Laravel setup

Tags: php, laravel

I am staring to learn about php frameworks and decided to go for laravel. I use netbeans 8.2 IDE to develop my projects and I followed the following instructions:

1. Install Composer on your system
2. Installer the Composer plugin for Netbeans (It's in the plugins menu, under the PHP category).
3. New Project > PHP Application
4. Go though the wizard, and setup your project. the last step should be named Composer
5. In the last step, search (under Token:) for laravel
6. Select laravel/laravel: The Laravel Framework. and move it to the selected frameworks on the right
7. Click Finish

So far so good, however, in the new project that is created, I do not see any of the file structure that i think should be there.

What I see:
[The file structure i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkpqq.png)

What i think i should see:
The file directory as explained in this:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/structure

So my question is:
Are there any steps I missed or I should do next to get this file structure already set up?

PS: I also know that I need the IDE helper to get autocompletion

Thank you in advance for taking the time to answer my question

Comment: Why aren't you using the `artisan` cli tools. For example : you can start a new laravel project with `laravel new myProject`. Using the `artisan` cli utilities will make your life easier.

Comment: have never used composer with netbeans

Comment: dont reply too much on IDEs, you will not learn the core of it

Comment: its the wrong way to start your laravel learning. download sublime text, install like in the documentation, and start using the artisan cli as recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. No I have never used composer before and will definitely check out artisan CLI tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Command prompt go to www location and type command for create project of laravel

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel yourprojectname
```

Comment: thanks! That actually worked! Though i dont know why. I'll be sure to google.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you follow [installation procedure form the Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation). Since you have Composer installed on your system, you can enter the command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectname
```

After that you can simply open your Laravel project folder in Netbeans, as a project. You can then very easily run your project in Netbeans by following this tutorial: http://markoivancic.from.hr/running-laravel-5-in-netbeans-8-using-php-built-in-web-server/